# SUMIFS and COUNT for PAST DUE SCHEDULE Mac Excel 14.7.2 (hyperlink for image)

Tags: worksheet-function

Trying to calculate how many loans in each past due ranges (COUNT) and also the amounts corresponding to the past due ranges (SUMIFS).  Is this an IF(AND type of formula?

[image]

Comment: This isn't making much sense. Please clarify exactly *what* you're trying to do.

Comment: click on the text you will see a screenshot. Usually if I am just trying to find out total loans per month is use a SUMIFS(loansrange:loansrange, daterange:daterange ">"&startofmonth, daterange,"<="&endofmonth) and that returns amounts for each month.  I can use COUNT and then just get the 'number' of loans by month.  In this scenario I am trying to find the 1. loans in a month and then 2. how past due they are (again the loans 'funded' in that month only).  So counting # of loans.  Also then need the 'dollar' amount of those loans past due.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is hard for me to decipher, so I made a sample spreadsheet that will hopefully demonstrate the same concepts.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Hopefully some of these formulas get you on the right track.Your question was pretty general and hard to understand, so I encourage you to clarify or ask some follow up questions if you can.